# Como puedo ejecutar un número desconocido de procesos?

Tags: c, linux

Necesito que mi código sea capaz de leer n líneas de stdin (que cada línea será una orden de la terminal de linux), se la de a un proceso hijo y la ejecute. Entonces cuando acabe ese proceso hijo el programa deberá volver a leer de texto y ejecutar otro proceso hijo para que así siempre hayan n procesos hijos en ejecución. He probado de diversas maneras pero siempre únicamente lee una línea aunque escriba varias mediante stdin y ejecuta un único proceso hijo y se queda a esperas de más entrada estándar. N deberá estar entre los valores 1 y 8.

La entrada estándar debe leerla en bloques de 16 bytes y cada orden no puede pesar más de 128 bytes.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 16

struct ordenes{
    int num;
    char *args[60];
};

typedef struct ordenes * ordenes;

void error(char * argv, int num_exit){
    fprintf(stderr,"Uso: %s [-p NUMPROC]\n",argv);
    fprintf(stderr,"Lee de la entrada estándar una sencuencia de líneas conteniendo órdenes para ser ejecutadas y lanza cada una de dichas órdenes en un proceso diferente.\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"-p NUMPROC     Número de procesos en ejecución de forma simultánea (1 <= NUMPROC <= 8)\n");
    exit(num_exit);
}

ordenes leer(){
    char * buf;
    if ((buf = (char *) malloc(BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char))) == NULL){
        perror("malloc()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    const char espacio[1] = " ";
    const char salto_linea[2] = "\n";
    char *token;
    ordenes orden = malloc(sizeof(orden));
    char *line = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*128);
    while((read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,BUF_SIZE))>0){
        strcpy(line,buf);
    }
    
    if(sizeof(line)>128){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Tamaño de línea mayor que 128.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    orden->num=0;
    token = strtok(line, espacio);
    orden->args[orden->num] = token;
    while(token != NULL){
        token = strtok(NULL, espacio);
        if(token!=NULL) {
            orden->num+=1;
            orden->args[orden->num] = token;
        }
    }
    orden->num+=1;
    orden->args[orden->num] = NULL;
    return orden;
}

int ejecutar_proceso(ordenes orden){
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    switch(pid = fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("fork()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
        case 0:
            execvp(orden->args[0],orden->args);
            fprintf(stderr,"execvp() failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
        default:
            if(waitpid(pid,&status,0) == -1){
                perror("wait()");
                free(orden);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            free(orden);
            break;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    
    char *arg1;
    char *arg2;
    int opt;
    int num_procesos=1;
    int num=num_procesos;
    

    if(argc > 3){
        error(argv[0],EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((opt = getopt(argc,argv,"p")) != -1){

        switch(opt){
            case 'p':
                if(argv[2]==NULL){
                    error(argv[0],EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                num_procesos = atoi(argv[2]);
                if(num_procesos < 1 || num_procesos > 8){
                    fprintf(stderr,"Error: el número de procesos en ejecución tiene que estar entre 1 y 8.");
                    error(argv[0],EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                break;
            default:
                num_procesos = 1;
                break;
        }

    }
    
    int i=0;
    while(i==0){
        if(num_procesos>0){
            ordenes orden = leer();
            num_procesos-=1;
            num_procesos += ejecutar_proceso(orden);
        }
    }

    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

El Makefile que debe ser capaz de compilarlo es el siguiente:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -ggdb3 -Werror -Wno-unused -std=c11 CC=gcc TARGETS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(wildcard *.c))

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
        -rm -rf $(TARGETS)

.PHONY: clean all
```

Y por ejemplo debe ser capaz de pasar pruebas como echo -e "ls -l\nls -l" | ./mycode

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! yo lei esto... num_procesos = 1;
y para mi, tu problema esta ahi, salvo que puedas demostrar lo contrario...

Comment: Al ejecutar el código se pasa como parámetro cuantos procesos se van a tener y el 1 es para que sea por defecto. Eso ya hice algo de depuración y está bien